# Use Zhu Ramanan code in a web application

Tags: php, c++, matlab, porting, face-detection

I have to use Face-eye detection algorithm by [Zhu Ramanan](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~xzhu/face/) in a web application. They have provided the code in Matlab and main computation is done in C++. Since I am new to image processing and matlab, i am not able to understand how to proceed on making it run with my web app.

I found that Matlab code can be ported to c++ by using coder function. So I tried using coder function in matlab which opened a Build menu wherein I selected C/C++ executable. But the build gets stuck when the code is loading a .mat file. It gives following error -

```
 Function 'load' implicitly resolved in the MATLAB workspace. Implicit evaluation
 in MATLAB is not supported. Please declare this function extrinsic using
 coder.extrinsic('load'), or call it using feval.
```

But both coder.extrinsic and feval are not compatible with C++.

I also read about a possibility of executing matlab file from php but that would be a very slow process (please correct me if i am wrong).

Can anyone please suggest whether I am going wrong and/or how should I proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code by Zhu and Ramanan uses a *learned* model to detect faces and fiducial points on them. The learned parameters are stored in a binary file of format `mat` used by Matlab. It appears as if the coder cannot port the `load` command that reads this file.

In order to fix this I'm afraid you'll have to get your hands a bit dirty. You'll need to replace the `mat` file with a different format and change the code accordingly.
Read the `mat` file in matlab using `load` and convert it into a different format of your choosing.  Change the code to read the new file using more basic commands (e.g., `fopen`, `fread` and the liking) then use the coder to port the modified code.

Comment: thnx for the prompt reply..i used `load('face_p146_small.mat');  
dlmwrite('face_p146_small.csv',load('face_p146_small.mat'));` inorder to write it in a csv file but it is giving me an error as mentioned [link](http://goo.gl/eVfoqZ). frankly i wasnt able to make sense out of it.Tried other methods as well but i am unable to use them as i have no experience with matlab. Please help.

Comment: @ShivangDoshi please look at the contents of the mat file you are trying to save. It's **not** just a bunch of numbers. They are arranged in components and parts. It's quite a complicated database to store the model. You'll have to do a more carefult job converting it. I would recommend you use some binary format, in order to keep the file size from exploding.

Comment: @ShivangDoshi Have you considered using `hdf5` file format? See [this help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/importing-hierarchical-data-format-hdf5-files.html). I'm not sure the coder supports this file type - so you'll have to verify this point.

Comment: no..im not aware of hdf5 format..will surely look into it and verify here....btw i just right now stumbled on https://github.com/wg-perception/PartsBasedDetector. Checking whether it actually is zhuramanan's c++ implementation

Comment: @ShivangDoshi seems related but not the same. I suspect you'll have to train models for yourself or you'll have the same problem converting model `mat` file...

Comment: yeah..didnt have any success with that..btw like you said i was trying to export the .mat to the hd5 format but the content in .mat file has datatype struc which cannot be stored in hd5 (hd5 only accepts numeric values). It gives `Error using ==> h5write at 54
Argument 'Data' failed validation isnumeric.` error. I am unsure whether I am using it correctly though here' my code `h5write('myfile.h5','/model/filters',model.filters,1,146);` and also tried `h5write('myfile.h5','/model/filters','face_p146_small.mat',1,146);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41543/discussion-between-shivang-doshi-and-shai)

Comment: @ShivangDoshi let's not. I'm not a big fan of chatting.