# Port Matlab code to C++ having .mat dataset

Tags: c++, matlab, porting, face-detection, hdf5

I am trying to export a `.mat` file which has data stored with datatype `struc` to a `hd5` format so as to make it compatible with c++ porting using `coder`. But `hd5` only accepts numeric values. The code is giving following error -

```
Error using ==> h5write at 54 Argument 'Data' failed validation isnumeric.
```

I am unsure whether I am using it correctly though here's my code

```
h5write('myfile.h5','/model/filters',model.filters,1,146);
```

and also tried but got same error -

```
h5write('myfile.h5','/model/filters','face_p146_small.mat',1,146);
```

My doubt is in continuation with my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088797/use-zhu-ramanan-code-in-a-web-application/20088924?noredirect=1#comment29942859_20088924). 
Any help regarding porting code from Matlab to C++ having data in .mat file format is much appreciated.

Comment: So are you absolutely sure that the C compiler by Matlab doesn't do the job on the fly such that you need to roll your own C code?

Comment: @phoeagon yup..i got the error as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/q/20088797/1958635 and also on the basis of the answer I got on that question.

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/13190#answer_18057) coder.extrinsic cannot be used unless creating a MEX file.

Comment: Have you look to `matio` to read .mat file instead of h5 ?

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau I had earlier looked into `mation` and i think using `matio` will only unable me to read .mat files but not in porting matlab code to c++. That i'll have to do manually..m i correct ?

Comment: Yes, it the easiest way to do it. I can take time because the indexing and memory don't work the same. But I think there a way like matlab to call C that you can call matlab from C++, but that not efficient. You still use matlab as processing source, when c++ is much much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer for my scenario. Since the algorithm I am using uses a very complex data, I need to use the binary data format but all the binary data formats supported by Matlab are not supported for conversion/porting to C++.

List of all the functions supported in conversion of Matlab code to C++

http://www.mathworks.in/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html

List of Data formats supported by Matlab

http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/import_export/supported-file-formats.html

It seems none of the functions data formats supported by matlab are supported in conversion.

Hence I will definitely have to rewrite the code